# PHP Serialize Failed & stored in semi-serialize format

Tags: javascript, php, json, serialization

When i add new category, i am storing child category in `serialize` format, Which works just perfect. Like :-

`a:1:{i:0;s:2:"41";}` But when i edit it back and try to change it to other category, which are loaded via `Ajax-Json Javascript`. But value is still `41` as above. It stores value in below format :-

`s:2:"41";`, Which is wrong and i get error while going back and editing it again.

Does any one know how this serialize failed to store in proper format ?,

Thanka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it Working, Oh, I had to dig and Understand what is `serialize` first and how `php` understands and converts it in `serialize` format.

Here you go from php.net

> String  s:size:value;
>
> Integer  i:value;
>
> Boolean  b:value; (does not store "true" or "false", does store '1'
>   or '0')
>
> Null  N;
>
> Array  a:size:{key definition;value definition;(repeated per
>   element)}
>
> Object  O:strlen(object name):object name:object
>   size:{s:strlen(property name):property name:property
>   definition;(repeated per property)}

That means, I was not sending value as array, and since value was not getting sent in array via HTML form, it didn't appended `a` for `array` tag. :)

And when i made my ``` HTML``input ``` field name as `category[]` from `category`, Everything worked as expected :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How are you editing it (code sample)?

You should unserialize it first, then modify, and serialize again.